# yield(:title) in Ruby on Rails is never equal to false for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
#layouts/application.html.haml
    %title
     = yield(:title) || "Default page title"
     = " | DefaultSite.com"


#application_helper.rb
 def title(page_title)
    content_for(:title) { page_title }
  end
```

Even if I don't set a `title` (helper method) for a page, `"Default page title"` never shows. Instead of it, `""` (the value of `yield(:title)`) appears for some reason.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just part of the design of Rails. You can't change this behaviour.

You should instead check if yield(:title).empty? is true or false in order to see if the content_for(:title) was called.

For example, instead of:

```
yield(:title) || "Default page title"
```

you want:

```
(yield(:title).empty? ? "Default page title" : yield(:title))
```

This just checks whether it is empty, and applies the default if it is empty, or else uses the title.

Comment: is this case I would use `present?` instead of `empty?`

Comment: I think you can use either. Just depends on which way round the arguments between the colons are placed.

Comment: You could also shorten this to `yield(:title).presence || "Default page title"`